# How well are the CSS2 'system colors' supported?

Tags: css, systemcolors

I've been reading the CSS2 spec in my spare time, and I've come across [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors). The note states that the system colours are deprecated, however, what is the browser support for the system colours part of the spec like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is **deprecated**. (it says so at the top of the link you provided)

It is not well supported, and is likely to get less so over time.

The intention of this feature was to provide the browser with access to the colour scheme of the underlying desktop operating system. However it has been dropped for several reasons. Desktop operating systems don't all have the same features, and furthermore the features they do have are open to change.

Finally, the main reason it was dropped is because the underlying reason for having them was to allow site designers to make their sites look like they belong to the parent OS. However there are other, better ways to achieve this now (notwithstanding the fact that most web site designers seem to prefer to have a consistent look and feel to their site that isn't dictated by the user).

See http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/CR-css3-color-20030514/#css-system for up-to-date info on this. At the bottom of this section is the following note:

> The CSS2 System Color values have been deprecated in favor of the CSS3 UI 'appearance' property for specifying the complete look of user interface related elements.

That should help tell you where to look for an up-to-date method of achieving a similar result.

The set of colours specified by the W3C in this page is roughly equivalent to the colour scheme values available in Windows 2000. This is obviously of limited use to someone running Windows XP, and no use at all to a Vista or Win7 user, let alone a Mac or Linux user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Spudley. Are the better methods available in the CSS3 spec (I read something about it on a link on the page I gave in my OP)?

Comment: +1 although you really did not have to bold the word deprecated since OP is already very aware of it :P

Comment: @BoltClock - the bolding is for the benefit of anyone else who finds this page in the future; they may not all be so well aware.

Comment: Thanks for your comments people - I'll stick to standard web colours then :-)

Comment: The `appearance` property is no longer in any CSS spec. Prefixed version `-webkit-` and `-moz-` are available, but officially, you still have to use the system colours which are deprecated but still supported.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what the support in different browsers for these values looks like, but you can test it for yourself by designing a small page using these, uploading it and testing it with
[Browsershot](http://browsershots.org/)