# Difference in website between FireFox and Edge

Tags: asp.net, firefox, webforms, microsoft-edge

I've got an issue with an old asp.net webforms application and I'd like to understand why this is happening. On the attached picture below, the exact same site is opened in Edge (on the left) and FireFox (on the right).

If you compare the 2 sites, you will see that the title bar text and label text is "missing" when compared to the right. I've figured out the that the cause of this is the **"color : background"** in the style.

If I uncheck this from dev tools on the left (or change it to red for instance), everything shows as the text is actually not missing - it's just white.  My question is why does Edge behave like this when compared to Firefox? And is there a fix/solution/work around for this in Edge?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color: background` belongs to [CSS2 System Color](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords#System_Colors) which is deprecated and has bad support in different browsers. You can also refer to this thread: [How well are the CSS2 'system colors' supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459699/how-well-are-the-css2-system-colors-supported). You should avoid to use the deprecated values.

If you want to set the text color, you can use a color name, a HEX value or an RGB value. For example `color: blue`.